# Integer solutions to $y^{2} = 2x^{2} +15x$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x,y \neq 0$.

This equation popped up in my friend's homework and it's quite a doozy. He's only supposed to find two possible solutions but we had to boot up Mathematica to find any ($x = 60$ and $2160$). I was wondering if there was anything we were missing, because this doesn't seem approachable with any of the Diophantine solving techniques we found online (e.g. Pell's equation, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for an $x$ such that $2x^2+15x = x(2x+15)$ is a perfect square.

Now, $\gcd(x, 2x+15) = \gcd(x,15)$, and working modulo $3$ and $5$ one quickly verifies that $x$ must be $0$ modulo $15$. So we have $x=15m$ and
$$ (15m)(30m+15) $$ is a perfect square, where $3\cdot 5$ are the only prime factors in common between the two factors. Thus $m$ is itself a perfect square; so set $m=k^2$ and we're looking for $k$ such that $2k^2+1 $ is a perfect square.

From here, trial and error can relatively quickly establish that $k=2$ and $k=12$ produce solutions.

Comment: And $2k^2+1=t^2$ is a Pell equation.

Comment: Could you explain how one can verify that $x \equiv 0 \mod 15$?

Comment: @SAWblade: Because it must be $0$ modulo $3$ and separately $0$ modulo $5$. For example, we have $2\cdot 1^2+15\cdot 1\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $2\cdot 2^2+15\cdot 2\equiv 2\pmod 3$, and $2$ is not a square of anything modulo $3$. So $x\equiv 0\pmod 3$ is th only possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very interesting, and I greatly appreciate your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $y^2=2x^2+15x$ is equivalent to $8y^2=(4x+15)^2-225$. Write $z=4x+15, 2y=w$. Then we get the equation $225= 3^2\cdot 5^2=z^2-2w^2$, so we can work  in the UFD $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$. The fundamental unit is $u=1+\sqrt2$ of norm $-1$. We also find that $3$ and $5$ are inert in this ring. Then if $\alpha=\pm3\cdot 5(1+\sqrt2)^{2k}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\alpha\tilde\alpha=225$. So:
$$z=\pm\frac{\alpha+\tilde\alpha}{2}=\pm\frac{3\cdot5}{2}((1+\sqrt2)^{2k}+(1-\sqrt2)^{2k})$$
$$w=\pm\frac{\alpha-\tilde\alpha}{2}=\pm\frac{3\cdot5}{2\sqrt2}((1+\sqrt2)^{2k}-(1-\sqrt2)^{2k})$$
Now we need find when $w\equiv 0 \mod 2R$.

But $(1+\sqrt2)^{2k}=(3+2\sqrt2)^k=(3+sign(k)\cdot 2\sqrt2)^{|k|}\equiv1\mod 2R$ , so $w$ is always divisible by $2$.

Also we need to find when $z-15\equiv 0 \pmod4\iff(3+2\sqrt2)^k+(3-2\sqrt2)^k\equiv 2 \pmod8$
$\iff\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(2\sqrt2)^i3^{k-i}+\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(-1)^i(2\sqrt2)^i3^{k-i}\equiv 2\pmod8$

$$\iff2\sum_{i=0\\i \;even}^k\binom{k}{i}(2\sqrt2)^i3^{k-i}\equiv 2\pmod8$$

I haven't yet found how to exactly calculate it, but I conjecture that for $k$ even, we get infinite solutions to this equation, and they must be all the solutions.

This would give for $u=1+\sqrt2$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$x=\pm \frac{3\cdot5}{8}(u^{4m}+\tilde u^{4m})-\frac{15}{4}$$
$$y=\pm \frac{3\cdot5}{4\sqrt2}(u^{4m}-\tilde u^{4m})$$

Comment: These formulas give me for $m\in\{1,2,...,6\}, x = 60, 2160, 73500, 2496960, 84823260, 2881494000$ and $y=90, 3060, 103950, 3531240, 119958210, 4075047900$

Comment: I like this solution. +1